# RPi Web Server: 403 forbidden on Apache

Tags: raspbian, web-server

I have created a web server with my Pi, and everything was working fine. I got the "It works!" page so I thought "Okay, everything's working". I then decided to upload a new index.html file. After uploading, everything is forbidden. Here's what Apache tells me when I navigate to it now:

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /admin on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server at blah blah
Did I do something to mess it up?

By the way, this is what I used as a tutorial: http://tinkernut.com/wiki/page/Episode_320

Comment: This also happened to me, using this tutorial: http://www.penguintutor.com/linux/raspberrypi-webserver
And then setting up FTP on my own (which I have had no problems with)

EDIT: Fixed this with @lenik 's comment in the answer. Works great now.

Comment: @Ben7005 I also learned that `find /opt/lampp/htdocs -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;` will chmod all the directories and subdirectories while `find /opt/lampp/htdocs -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;` will chmod all the files within the specified directory. Obviously you replace `/opt/lampp/htdocs` with whatever folder path you need to chmod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should not type `192.168.2.37/admin` in your browser, just the address part: `192.168.2.37` (your real address most probably would be different in the last two numbers, like `192.168.XXX.XXX`)

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But even the index.html file is "foribidden"

Comment: please, use `ls -al` in your web server root directory (where you have uploaded `index.html`) and see who is the owner of the files, and what are the permissions. basically, the owner is supposed to be `www-data` or something and permissions should be like `rw-r--r--`, you may fix the owner with `chown owner:owner file` command and the permissions with `chmod 0644 file` command.